# How to make relative Div dragable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html

```
<div class="main_box">
<div class="dragable_box"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
div.main_box{
    width:320px;
    height:480px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
div.dragable_box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    position: absolute;
}
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dragable_box").on("mousedown",function(){
        $(document).on("mousemove",function(event){
            $(".dragable_box").css({
                left: event.pageX,
                top: event.pageY
            })
        })
    })
})
```

When i click on dragable_box, it does not move along with the mouse pointer. 
Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ry6Lp4st/).

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong???

Comment: use jquery plugin https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

```
div.main_box{
    width:320px;
    height:480px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
   \*position: relative;*\
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

The `position: relative;` for the parent and `position: absolute;` to its child make the child to move according to the parent so if you remove the `postion:relative` in the above class it will work fine.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ry6Lp4st/3/)

Comment: What if I want to absolutely position "dragable_box" div with respect to "main_box" div, then I have to use relative position for main div.
Is there any other way without removing the position property of main div???

Comment: @iexploit if u want to do it you have to manually calculate the `left` and `top` values respective to the `position:relative` div. so that when you drag it left wards from the `position:relative` container it produces negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your JQuery code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main_box").on("mousedown",function(){
        $(document).on("mousemove",function(event){
            $(".dragable_box").css({
                left: event.pageX,
                top: event.pageY
            })
        })
    })
})
```